# Performance Issues With System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory+ServiceHttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, asynchronous, newrelic

I've recently started using NewRelic to take a look at some performance issues with my web application. I noticed there is a large performance issue being reported in `System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory+ServiceHttpHandler`

After taking a look at a single slow request NewRelic reports:

[image]

The site used a WCF service that is setup to handle request using async and I believe the ServiceHttpGandlerFactory maybe waiting on requests to finish?

I've done some looking around and one issue was regarding a possible issue with session state, which I have since disabled.

At this point I'm stuck, I've ran a profiler locally and things look good which makes me believe this is an issue under load or a intermittent issue. Does anyone know what else I should look at or what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using a recent version of the New Relic agent.  Version 3.2.113.0 added better support for WCF services (see https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/net-release-notes/net-agent-321130).

If async activity is going on then the agent is likely unable to associate that with the ongoing transaction.  That could be because HttpContext or OperationContext is not available to the agent.  Async activity might be lumped in the non-web category.

It could be that [custom instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/net-custom-instrumentation) may help in this situation, especially [custom transactions](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/net-custom-transactions) if async is in play.